# Getting failed expectations from GMock

Tags: c++, googlemock

Currently, I am using GMock without GTest ( specifically, I'm using it with mstest ). Is there any way to get a string of the failed expectations ?

IE:

```
EXPECT_CALL( mockObject, MethodWith3Params( 1, 2, 3 ) ).Times(1);

// Do does not call MethodWith3Params at all.
stuffDoer.Do( mockObject);

Assert::IsTrue( Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations( &mockObject ), " "/*What can I do here to say what expectation/s failed ?*/ );
```

I assume GMock is storing these strings ( or at least raw data that can be used to deduce a message ) somewhere, since GTest is able to tell you when an expectation isn't met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a class that inherits from `::testing::EmptyTestEventListener` and instantiate it within the test.  Refer to the Google Test Advanced Guide:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#extending-googletest-by-handling-test-events

Comment: @Kindread can you post an example of how you achieved this (since this is an accepted answer)? I'm specifically looking for an MSTEST example.